# How do I close a jquery contextMenu?

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I'm using [a jquery contextMenu plug-in](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/) and have a small issue I'm trying to resolve.

Currently when I click my 'delete' menu item the function I call prompts the user with a confirmation box from the deleteTests function. At this point the contextMenu is still visible and the confirmation box.

Ideally I would like to close the contextMenu as soon as the user selects a menu item and then proceed to the delete function.

This seems like it should be trivial but I can't seem to get it working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.contextMenu({selector: '#context-menu', items: {
    "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete", callback: menu_click },
    sep1: "---------",
    quit: {name: "Quit", icon: "quit", callback: $.noop}
}});

function menu_click(key, opt) {
    if (key == "delete") {
    // Need to close menu here
        deleteTests();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: _Which_ jQuery context menu? Provide a link.

Comment: sorry about that: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. It should be trivial, but the author did not provide this functionality.

You can look at the source and copy whatever the author did when clicks outside of the menu are detected, but this is a hack.

---

You're in luck; I've done the same thing with this plug-in myself.

The following will do, but remember that *it's a hack*:

```
$('.contextMenu').hide();
```

Comment: hmm, it isn't working for me. The menu still persists until I acknowledge my confirmation dialog from the deleteTests() function.

Comment: @Paul: Then you're not performing that line of code before you pop up the confirmation dialog.

Comment: here is my current code:  function menu_click(key, opt) {

     $('.contextMenu').hide(); 

     if (key == "delete") {
  deleteTests();
     }
 }

Comment: I'm using chrome and don't see any issues...I'll keep poking at it. Thanks!

Comment: this call did the trick for me: $('.context-menu-list').hide();

Comment: @Paul: Cool. It may just be a difference between versions. This highlights the nature of the hack ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can try to trigger `contextmenu:hide`

```
$('.context-menu-list').trigger('contextmenu:hide')
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer, as per the documentation: https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs/events.html#contextmenuhide. The other answer using $('.contextMenu').hide() leaves it in the DOM.

Comment: This should be flagged as the correct answer. $('.contextMenu').hide() only makes visibility of the menu to 'hidden' but the menu is still there!